# Touch input and direct manipulation

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, touch, swipe

I am listening to several events to handle touch input in my Windows (Phone) 8.1 Runtime code. This works well as long as no `ScrollViewer` is involved. The `ScrollViewer` swallows all gesture events due to [Direct Manipulation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh446969.aspx).

Here are the events I listen to now (`view` is a `FrameworkElement`):

```
        var cw = Window.Current.CoreWindow;
        cw.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
        cw.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;
        cw.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
        cw.PointerCaptureLost += OnPointerCaptureLost;

        view.Tapped += onTap;
        view.DoubleTapped += onDoubleTap;
        view.Holding += onHold;
        view.ManipulationDelta += onManipulationDelta;
        view.ManipulationCompleted += onManipulationCompleted;
```

As soon as the `ScrollViewer` recognizes a tap, I get a PointerCaptureLost and no other event handlers are called anymore.

[Rob Caplan wrote in 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/16/where-did-all-my-gestures-go.aspx):

> Unfortunately there is no good solution if the app needs both scrolling and gestures (for example, to detect CrossSlides against the scrolling). In this case the only option to get the Pointer messages everywhere is to disable Direct Manipulation everywhere, but that disables scrolling as well. To get that back the app will need to detect the scrolling gestures itself and then navigate the ScrollViewer to the new location with ScrollToHorizontalOffset or ScrollToVerticalOffset or by updating the SelectedIndex. This is tricky and will be noticeably slower than letting the ScrollViewer do its thing. It should be avoided if at all possible.

Has that changed in the meantime? Does anybody know a sample which does that?

I am writing an abstraction which transforms the gesture events into different events. The user can place any controls in it and I also don't know, what he may do with it. So I cannot slow it down just to get the gesture events.

Are there any other controls beside the `ScrollViewer` which behave similarly?

Can a `Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer` help? As the `UIElement` already provides all events I need, I didn't try it - and I don't understand why anybody should.

Comment: here a link with the same issue:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/16/where-did-all-my-gestures-go.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Why not use some transparent layer above the ScrollViewer and then forward events to it (either after first having done your processing, or waiting for it to process them first, but remembering which ones they were to act on them afterwards too)?